# Is there a generic way to printf a variable?

Tags: c, macros, printf

If I have a macro like

```
#define MYMACRO(x) printf ("%any\n", x);
```

is there any `%any` formatter which can print anything, context-dependently?

Non-standard or GNU C specific are OK.

Comment: No. No. No. No.

Comment: You should use %s and write a function that convert integers, floatings and characters to a string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: Rewritten to focus more on the macro aspect.

If you limit yourself to a single argument, it's doable in [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) using [generics](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html). The linked-to page has an example, the gist of which is to use generics to map the type of the argument to the proper formatting string.

I don't want to "re-print" the entire blog post, but the macro begins:

```
#define printf_dec_format(x) _Generic((x), \
    char: "%c", \
    signed char: "%hhd", \
    unsigned char: "%hhu", \
   /* more code deleted */

#define print(x) printf(printf_dec_format(x), x)
#define printnl(x) printf(printf_dec_format(x), x), printf("\n");
```

Comment: The question by itself makes sense though, as `cout` does that in C++ (using function overloading of course, but still).

Comment: The same way as `typeof`.

Comment: @ChewyDragees But `typeof` is *not* an ordinary function. It's a built-in operator ...

Comment: @unwind - my question is about a macro method to do this, so I would be thinking of a compile-time way of changing the formatting.

Comment: You could probably cobble something together with C11's `_Generic` capability, but it would be ugly.

Comment: @ChewyDragees I failed to focus on the macro aspect, my apologies. I rewrote.

Comment: "*... doable in C99 ...*" err ... you most probably wanted to say "*... in C11*"?

Comment: @alk D'oh! Of course. Corrected (and linked), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the value of a **numeric expression**, without wanting to tell the compiler if it's signed or unsigned (i.e. without `%u` flags etc.) or if it's `long`, `long long` or whatever...
...then there's a way that works with old C standards also (C99, C90, ...).

Just use the macro [`P99_SIGNED`](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__integers_ga3eb39ccac28ebd8265c1a31dc00f53ab.html#ga3eb39ccac28ebd8265c1a31dc00f53ab) from the find P99 project -- it also works for old C standards.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <limits.h> /* CHAR_BIT, LLONG_MIN, etc. */

/* http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__integers_ga3eb39ccac28ebd8265c1a31dc00f53ab.html 

   P99 homepage: http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/
   P99 repo:     https://scm.gforge.inria.fr/anonscm/gitweb?p=p99/p99.git;a=tree
*/
#define P99_SIGN_PROMOTE(A, B) (1 ? (A) : (B))
#define P99_PROMOTE_0(EXPR)    P99_SIGN_PROMOTE(0, (EXPR))
#define P99_PROMOTE_M1(EXPR)   P99_SIGN_PROMOTE(-1, (EXPR))
#define P99_SIGNED(EXPR)      (P99_PROMOTE_M1(EXPR) < P99_PROMOTE_0(EXPR))


#define print_num(x) (P99_SIGNED(x)                                     \
                      ? printf("%lld", (  signed long long)(x))         \
                      : printf("%llu", (unsigned long long)(x)))

int main()
{
  print_num(-1);           /* prints -1 */
  putchar('\n');

  print_num(1);            /* prints 1 */
  putchar('\n');

  print_num(LLONG_MIN);    /* prints -9223372036854775808 (dependant on archi) */
  putchar('\n');

  print_num(ULLONG_MAX);   /* prints 18446744073709551615 (dependant on archi) */
  putchar('\n');

  return 0;
}
```

This can also be a big help in understanding integer promotion rules, since using e.g. `print_num(-1+0U)` you'll see that the compiler promotes all operands to unsigned (you get a large positive value!)

As has been mentioned by others: If you have a compiler that can handle C11 or newer: use `_Generic` -> [Link](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html). under the heading *Printing values generically*.

Comment: Small note, as of [January 2013](https://gitlab.inria.fr/gustedt/p99/-/commit/e140703b3c46d91f4eef2730c6347a9bafdb0df1), the macro `P99_SIGNED` is using `P99_PROMOTE_1` instead of `P99_PROMOTE_0`